# How to find if two characters are in an array php

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I am looking to develop a search function that allows users to just search for the item, or modify their search with a price range in brackets. So that is to say if they are looking for a car, then they can enter either car and receive all cars in the database or they can enter car (100, 299) or car(100, 299) and receive only cars in the database with the price range of 100 to 299.

Before what I did was three different explode function calls, but that was cumbersome and looked ridiculously ugly. I also tried to put the the brackets in an array and then compare that against the word searched (a word is basically an array of characters) but that didn't work. Finally I have been reading up on strpos and substr but they don't seem to fit the requirements as strpos returns the first occurrence of the the character and substr returns the characters within a specified length after a specific occurrence.

So for example the problem with strpos is the user can just enter ( and no ) bracket and I'll make a call to my search function with who knows what. And for example the problem with substr is that the price range can vary wildly.

Comment: I would suggest going with search filters like many current sites do instead of search keywords with brackets. Users are going to have a hard time with non-standard keyword searches.

Comment: I was thinking that too. At first I had two other search input fields, denoting min and max price. However it looked ugly and not really unique. I'm trying to basically develop a classifieds site that you can search for what you want in what ever price range and not have to modify your search later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match to parse the search string - I'm assuming that's the part you're having issues with.

```
if (preg_match('/car ?\(([^,]+), ?([^\)]+)\)/', $search_text, $matches)) {
    $low_price = $matches[1];
    $high_price = $matches[2];

    //do your price filtering here
}
```

The regular expression may need a little tweaking, I don't remember offhand if parentheses need to be escaped in character classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sam is right. You should do this with regular expressions.

Look for [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on the documentation

To complete his answer, the regular expression for your case is:

```
$regex = "^([a-zA-Z]+)\s\(([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\)$"

if (preg_match($regex, $search_text, $matches)) {
    $type = $matches[0];
    $low_price = $matches[1];
    $high_price = $matches[2];

    //do your price filtering here
}
```

Be careful, as the array containing matches starts at index 0, not one.

Comment: That regular expression definitely won't work - it needs delimiters on the start and end, and sub-patterns to capture the numbers individually.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited the code with this regex : ^([a-zA-Z]+)\s\(([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\)$